# Multiple Script tags in html not working when combining 2 html files

Tags: html

I am trying to combine 2 html file together. Both working fine when using separately. But when i am trying to combine them they are losing formatting.

w3 containers are not showing correctly. It only shows the graph and above graph is non formatted text.

I try to place the scripts at different places but not much with success.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<head>
<title>ESXI AD Authentication Report</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "light2",
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Shares of Electricity Generation by Fuel"
    },
    subtitles: [{
        text: "United Kingdom, 2016",
        fontSize: 16
    }],
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        indexLabelFontSize: 18,
        radius: 80,
        indexLabel: "{label} - {y}",
        yValueFormatString: "###0.0\"%\"",
        click: explodePie,
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 42, label: "Gas" },
            { y: 21, label: "Nuclear"},
            { y: 24.5, label: "Renewable" },
            { y: 9, label: "Coal" },
            { y: 3.1, label: "Other Fuels" }
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();
function explodePie(e) {
    for(var i = 0; i < e.dataSeries.dataPoints.length; i++) {
        if(i !== e.dataPointIndex)
            e.dataSeries.dataPoints[i].exploded = false;
    }
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<div class="w3-container w3-light-blue">
  <h1>ESXI AD Authentication Report</h1>  
</div>
<div class="w3-bar w3-light-grey">
    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
      <button class="w3-button">Vcenter Configured</button>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
        <a href="http://esxi_auth/AMDC-NPN" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">b1</a>
        <a href="http://esxi_auth/AMDC-Prod" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">b2</a>
      </div>   
    </div>
<div class="w3-bar-item"></div>
    <div class="w3-bar-item">Last Updated: #date#</div>
  </div>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;">
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to use w3's **CSS** into your HTML, ie you should put this line in `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" type="text/css" />
```

so your code became below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<head>
    <title>ESXI AD Authentication Report</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "light2",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title: {
                    text: "Shares of Electricity Generation by Fuel"
                },
                subtitles: [{
                    text: "United Kingdom, 2016",
                    fontSize: 16
                }],
                data: [{
                    type: "pie",
                    indexLabelFontSize: 18,
                    radius: 80,
                    indexLabel: "{label} - {y}",
                    yValueFormatString: "###0.0\"%\"",
                    click: explodePie,
                    dataPoints: [
                        { y: 42, label: "Gas" },
                        { y: 21, label: "Nuclear" },
                        { y: 24.5, label: "Renewable" },
                        { y: 9, label: "Coal" },
                        { y: 3.1, label: "Other Fuels" }
                    ]
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
            function explodePie(e) {
                for (var i = 0; i < e.dataSeries.dataPoints.length; i++) {
                    if (i !== e.dataPointIndex)
                        e.dataSeries.dataPoints[i].exploded = false;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="w3-container w3-light-blue">
        <h1>ESXI AD Authentication Report</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-bar w3-light-grey">
        <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
            <button class="w3-button">Vcenter Configured</button>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
                <a href="http://esxi_auth/AMDC-NPN" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">b1</a>
                <a href="http://esxi_auth/AMDC-Prod" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">b2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-bar-item"></div>
        <div class="w3-bar-item">Last Updated: #date#</div>
    </div>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;">
        <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only in case i open it from chrome using web link of the IIS site i have created, it do not show graph, but when i open it locally , it is showing me the graph. <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

Comment: you must make sure to that this script load successfully in IIS site, in network tab of chrome's developer tools, can you see this script file was transferred with status 200?

Comment: issue is with https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js , this file. It is not loading because of chrome restrictions.

Comment: @Asharma5, if this answer resolving your problem, you must accept it, and if this is helpful, you must up-vote it, don't you? all of answers for your questions have been left unapproved, why?